# Using terraform 0.12 functions to fetch a value from list of maps

Tags: terraform

Using [Auth0 provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/auth0) I need to to create a [custom_domain](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/auth0/r/custom_domain.html#verification). In order for it to be validated, user needs to create a DNS record with a CNAME generated during the process. `verification` resource looks like this in the tfstate file:

```
"verification": [
  {
    "methods": [
      {
        "name": "cname",
        "record": "some-random-cname.auth0.com"
      }
    ]
  }
],
```

- So far I was able to get a tuple of maps(according to tfstate file), but still can't get the `record` value

```
resource "auth0_custom_domain" "main" {
  domain              = "custom.example.com"
  type                = "auth0_managed_certs"
  verification_method = "txt"
}

locals {
  something = flatten(auth0_custom_domain.main.verification[*].methods)
}

output "my-local" {
  value = local.something
}
```

- With output looking like this:

```
my-local = [
  {
    "name" = "cname"
    "record" = "some-random-cname.auth0.com"
  },
]
```

- It seems I am close in getting that record and use it as input for the route53 entry, but yet I can't get it, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I finally managed to do it like this but I'll leave it open in case there is a better solution:
  ```something = lookup(element(flatten(auth0_custom_domain.main.verification[*].methods), 0), "record")```

Comment: You should consider posting that as a self answer and then see if anyone can think of something better. That looks pretty reasonable to me though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `ydaetskcoR` suggested this is how I managed to solve it, but it looks to me like it's too complex, so I would like to see if anyone has a better solution than this:

```
something = lookup(element(flatten(auth0_custom_domain.main.verification[*].methods), 0), "record")
```

Comment: The only further improvement I'd suggest here is to use the index and attribute access syntaxes, rather than the `lookup` and `element` functions: `auth0_custom_domain.main.verification[0].methods[0].record`. Note that this assumes that you only care about the first `method` object inside the first `verification` object; it will ignore any additional ones.

Comment: @MartinAtkins I remember this was the first way I tried and it didn’t work ‘